# I want to insert a row into a table and insert 3 cells with content into that row. My function is only inserting one cell

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-table, local-storage

I have form in my HTML and upon submitting it my JavaScript function takes in the data and then takes the user to a new page. The new page has a table and allows the user to click a button that inserts the information from the form into a new row. When I do this the new row is inserted but only with one cell of information.

Here is the HTML Form:

```
<form class="popup-content" action="my-picks.html" method="get">
    <h2>My Bet</h2>
    <div class="content-line">
        <span>Pick:</span>
        <p class="choice" id="bet-choice"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="choice-odds" class="content-line">
        <span>Odds:</span>
        <input type="text" class="choice" id="odds-choice">
    </div>
    <div id="choice-conf" class="content-line">
        <span>Confidence (1-10):</span>
        <input type="number" class="choice" id="conf-choice" min="0" max="10">
    </div>
    <button class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</button>
    <button class="submit-btn" onclick="getData()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is the HTML table and button (on a different HTML document)

```
<button id="show-bets" onclick="showBets()">Show New Bets</button>
<div class="bet-upcoming">
    <h3>Upcoming Bets</h3>
    <table id="tbl-upcoming">
        <thead>
            <th>Game</th>
            <th>Pick</th>
            <th>Odds</th>
            <th>Confidence</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <!--JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION FILLS OUT TABLE-->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And here are the JavaScript Functions

```
function getData() {
    document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");

    var betChoice = document.getElementById("bet-choice").innerHTML;
    var oddsChoice = document.getElementById("odds-choice").innerHTML;
    var confChoice = document.getElementById("conf-choice").innerHTML;

    localStorage.setItem("value1", betChoice);
    localStorage.setItem("value2", oddsChoice);
    localStorage.setItem("value3", confChoice);

}

var list1 = [];
var list2 = [];
var list3 = [];
var n = 1;
var x = 0;

function showBets() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl-upcoming");
    var newRow = table.insertRow(-1);

    list1[x] = localStorage.getItem("value1");
    list2[x] = localStorage.getItem("value2");
    list3[x] = localStorage.getItem("value3");

    var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);

    cell1.innerHTML = list1[x];
    cell2.innerHTML = list2[x];
    cell3.innerHTML = list3[x];

    n++;
    x++;
}
```

Comment: When you click on the submit button, it will reload the page unless you use `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I think another way is to add `type="button"` to your submit button. It works for me.

Comment: Although the above comments are correct for the form auto submission. The actual cause of your local storage ONLY storing the last values is because you need to store a JSON string of the data and parse it. Otherwise you will keep overwriting the data with the last input. Also for input fields use **value** not **innerHTML**

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, I think you would not need to use the `<form>` tag. Then it will not submit when they click on the submit button (except by your JavaScript code which is what you want). Also, it will not submit if the user presses the enter key (something I often do and then regret).